# How to fix error in lookup type for typescript?

Tags: typescript, dictionary, types, type-conversion, lookup

**My Problem:** A minimal example for my problem is ([typescript play example with the code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=3.9.0-dev.20200224&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBA0sCeBnKBvKAzA9pqBeKARFpgQDRQBGAhgE56HU0FQC+AUG+mCAMYAuAS0wgoAc2B8APAEEowAB59QAE2Rwk5AEIA+ABRsohqMoH8AXKigBtGFAEjpAXQD8Fza1IGjAawQXpbACUblAAPlDgADaRqF6GPMKIfFA0wIhgkcn4JvxWvvCOHEZ26FC6fPAADsCY6Lqp6ZmBUACEuPgE3MrA6PbAygTNKHHFKRJgNCINGXwjLHKRiMCxo0apfBMiUZFzbCxAA)):

```js
enum Keys { foo = "foo", bar = "bar" }

function getValue<A extends Keys, B>(dict: { [K in A]?: B }, key: A): B | null
{
    const result = dict[key]

    if (result !== undefined) {
        return result
    } else {
        return null
    }
}
```

Typescript gives the following type checking error for the statement `return result`:

```
Type 'B | undefined' is not assignable to type 'B | null'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'B | null'.
```

**My question:** Why does the type guard `result !== undefined` not work in the above example and how can I fix it?

**My attempts:**

- When I inspect the example in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html I see that the variable `result` has the type `{ [K in A]?: B | undefined; }[A]`. However I have expected that typescript automatically can reduce it to `B | undefined`. Maybe I have an error in the type declaration of `A` or `dict` so that typescript cannot reduce the lookup type...
- The error occurs also in the current nightly version `3.9.0-dev.20200224`.
- Changing the typeguard to `typeof(result) !== "undefined"` does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems like a bug or design limit of TSC for now. It cannot reduce `{ [K in A]?: B | undefined; }[A]` to `B | undefined` immediately, so you can either cast  result to `B | undefined` or move `Keys` out of generic

```
const enum Keys { foo = "foo", bar = "bar" }

function get<B>(
    dict: { [K in Keys]?: B },
    key: Keys
): B | null {
    const result = dict[key]

    if (result !== undefined) {
        return result
    } else {
        return null
    }
}
```

also I suggest always use const enum

Answer (score 1):

> My question: What is the error in the above code example and how can I fix it? It seems that the type guard result !== undefined does not work...

One way to "fix" it is to return `undefined` consistently instead of returning `null`. The following works as an API but, as @Austaras correctly says, it does not effectively narrow `result` to `B` within the type guard.

```
function getValueOne<A extends Keys, B>(
    dict: { [K in A]?: B },
    key: A
): B | undefined {
    const result = dict[key]

    if (result !== undefined) {
        return result; // result is { [K in A]?: B | undefined; }[A]
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

Another way to "fix" it is to use an explicit type like this:

```
function getValueToo<A extends Keys, B>(
    dict: { [K in A]?: B },
    key: A
): B | null {
    const result: B | undefined = dict[key];

    if (result) {
        return result; // result is B
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This third approach might be my favorite, because it is the most general of the three. We change the return type.

```
function getValueThree<A extends Keys, B>(
    dict: { [K in A]?: B },
    key: A
): (typeof dict)[A] {
    const result = dict[key]

    if (result !== undefined) {
        return result;
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

[All three are in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=3.9.0-dev.20200224#code/KYOwrgtgBA0sCeBnKBvKAzA9pqBeKARFpgQDRQBGAhgE56HU0FQC+AUG+mCAMYAuAS0wgoAc2B8AalQA2YYAHkQwADwBBKMAAefUABNkcJOQBCAPgAUbKDah6B-AFyooAbRhQBItQF0A-M4mrKTWtgDWCM5qbACUgVAAPlDcesDoXsB6qKE2PMKIfFA0wIhgMoX49vyuEfA+HLae6FAWxaXlUACEuPgpaRl6MdmNjcV8YDQibWV8ANw5rJoyiMDDIzZjEyJ96cp6843s7Jzc-EIi4lKy8gAq2OqaOvqGCIimlgtVfM5o7p7e-niLBCjVqUVi8SS4BkMjWuXyhWm5UhyRAqV2mXoXxqCB88wWAmarRKMyGKAWowkWyKJPKB1sLCWKzhI02kyg0Jk9JsRw4XF4gmEYgk0jkwBuAAtiqoNNpdGiXsYoOYrI0vj83B4vFBfAFlcEFmCdRCWnx4AAHYCYZpfGKuXyJDllWHkxp5EAFGntCp2Bx8HF1Bq2QktJGFbq9NH9PZkim2NlTWlzBaM4DLVau9Y08bsznc1hsY7uz1feiZmzEZwAcgAklAqNBiFWQbZGNW6w3KLRm4X8cXCgA3ACM9EuovkSmAFi+5CMiAAdMQYn2EVABwAmUci67i7DTv2z16L7DLjj9tcAZi3VzFkul+-4h6Qx8wy6AA).